# Suitable data structure for large graphs

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dijkstra

I have a large graph, is there any other data structure other than adjacency list and "adjacency matrix" in c++ stl or some other data structure which I can employ for such a large graph, actually the adjacency matrix of my graph does not fit in the main memory. My graph is directed and I am implementing dijkstra algorithm in C++.

I have seen the previous posts...but I am searching for a suitable data structure with respect to dijkstra.

By large I mean a graph containing more than 100 million nodes and edges.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Thanks for replying.. I have defined

Comment: There is a graph lib already in boost

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Yes, but it is exceptionally hard to use.

Answer (score 2):

It's common to represent adjacency lists as lists of integers, where the integer is the index of a node.  How about getting some more space efficiency by instead treating the adjacency list as a bit string `00010111000...` where a `1` in nth position represents an edge between this node and node `n`?  Then compress the bitstring by some standard algorithm; uncompress it as you need it.  The bit strings will probably compress pretty well, so this trades space efficiency for higher computational cost.

Comment: Not a bad idea! I may need to use this at some point :). If he's using C++ though, a `std::bitset` might work better.

Comment: Ya..this is the same as adjacency matrix